# SQL Reporting Services 2005 - Filter data by Active Directory Security Group

Tags: active-directory, reportingservices-2005

Is there a way, in a report, to filter data by AD group?
I need to make it so "Group A" can see all data and "Group B" sees less.
I can't change anything in the DB and the just the user name is passed to the report.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You make two reports, one that shows all the data one that shows less. You give access to first report to Group A, you give access to second report to Group B.

**Update**

You create two reports, one named ReportGroupA, one named ReportGroupB. In the report editor you go to Details/Security for ReportGroupA and add the GroupA to the 'Browser' role. Then you go to Detail/Security for ReportGroupB and add GroupB to the 'Browser' role. Done. Group A can see only report ReportGroupA, Group B can see only report Report Group B. For more information see  [Role-based Access to Reports and Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157323.aspx).